# Undetermined type error in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement wherein i have to convert a dictionary into dataframe, below is the dictionary:

```
{'col1': None, 'product_volume_override': '1', 'col2': '70', 'col3': None},{'col1': None, 'col2': '1', 'col3': '70'}
```

Below is the spark code for same:

```
spark_df = sc.parallelize([{'col1': None, 'col2': '70', 'col3': None},{'col1': None, 'col2': '1', 'col3': '70'}]).toDF()
```

However it is throwing below error to me:

```
ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling
```

This error is coming when a particular column value is null for all records.

Can someone please help me with the pyspark implementation to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a schema for your dataframe and use `nullable=True`, for columns which you have  null values.

```
y = StructType([StructField("col1",StringType(), nullable = True), 
                StructField("col2",StringType(), nullable = True),
                StructField("col3",StringType(), nullable = True),
               StructField("col4",StringType(), nullable = True)])
```

Now provide this schema to `toDF()` method

```
spark_df = sc.parallelize([{'col1': None, 'col2': '70', 'col3': None},{'col1': None, 'col2': '1', 'col3': '70'}]).toDF(schema = y)
spark_df.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|null|  70|null|null|
|null|   1|  70|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: yes, and to add: spark cannot infer schema because `col1` has Null for all rows in your example. If you would add another row but with actuall value you will not get any errors